# How to use GitHub fine-grained access tokens in production across many repos when the max expiration is a year?

Tags: python, github, requirements.txt, personal-access-token, github-fine-grained-tokens

I am trying to transition from the GitHub `Personal Access Tokens` classic version to the currently beta version `fine-grained tokens`. My issue is the token expiration max age is 1 year, whereas before the classic tokens could be set to not have any expiration. I know the simplest solution is just use the classic tokens, but if I've learned anything from GitHub's beta programs is that they will deprecate the previous option eventually. The `fine-grained tokens` are also appealing given they limit access to 1+ specific repositories.

I understand the reasons behind the expiration but am having an issue reconciling how to handle it. My issue is I have python packages hosted on GitHub using private repositories. I have a `requirements.txt` using the token to install the package(s) in the private repository(s) in multiple applications/scripts being hosted on the cloud or ran locally on multiple machines. If I only had one repository it would be a simple update, but there are many programs consuming these private packages. So, when the token(s) inevitably expires (max age is currently a year) I will then need to update the `requirements.txt` for all repositories that use the private repository package(s).

I realize I could store the token in a separate file and reference the token. However, this doesn't seem like a proper approach given the syntax appears so convoluted.

```
-e git+https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git@TAG#egg=PACKAGE_NAME&
subdirectory=PACKAGE_DIRECTORY&oauth_token=$(cat PATH/TO/FILE.TXT)
```

This solution also doesn't solve the case where I have an CD `GitHub Action` that deploys an application to AWS that needs to install the private repositories' packages. I would need to store the `fine-grained token(s)` as a Secret for the repository to be used in the `GitHub Action`. Then when the token inevitably updates I will have to go to every repository and update it.

I created the `fine-grained access` tokens and began using them but ran into the issues described above.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate approach here is not to store the token in the `requirements.txt` file at all.  That file is visible to everyone who has your project, and a GitHub token is a secret.  Secrets should not be checked into your repository since it's very easy for them to accidentally leak.

Instead, the thing to do is use a credential helper.  On most OSes, there is a built-in credential helper that the user can use to save a suitable token and when Git is invoked, it can prompt for credentials if they're needed.

If you're working in a CI environment, such as GitHub Actions, generate a single token that works for all the repositories you need (which is possible with fine-grained tokens), store it in the appropriate secret store, expose it in the environment, and then use [the technique outlined in the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment) to read the token from the environment.

If you don't want to use a fine-grained token because of the expiration, you can [create a GitHub App](https://docs.github.com/en/apps/overview), which can issue tokens on your behalf.  These tokens will be short-lived and have fine-grained permissions, but they can be issued on demand in a programmatic way, so you can have your infrastructure issue a token for the duration of your CI/CD job and then it will automatically be expired.  For users, the need to regenerate a token from time to time should not be too burdensome.